# How can I turn a matrix into a polygon

Tags: java, matrix, graphics, libgdx, polygon

I want to be able to take an image as a matrix and turn it into a polygon.

The image will be a irregular shape with many angles and essentially find its outer edges that can be processed into a polygon (array of vertices)

The image is already encoded so I can get all of its pixels that make the total shape (filled). I know how I can get an origin for it and offset the other pixels with it.

[background] 
I am trying to make Risk into a game. I want to map all the territories as polygons so I can do mouse detection on them.

I know that I can just pass the mouse x,y and iterate through the pixels, but the map is large and that would not be very efficient.

Note: I plan on using libgdx's polygon library to map it. It takes a single dimensional array of floats for its vertices.

Comment: "Risk into a game" *face palm* a digital/programmed/java application...

Comment: By image to polygon, do you mean just map the 2D image onto a flat polygon so the mouse can just click on an x,y point?

Comment: OK, I think I see where this is going with the libgdx library.  I assume the correct way to do this is "manually."  For each map/image you have you'll have to outline the territories by hand and then feed that list to the library method as a separate parameter.

Comment: "you'll have to outline the territories by hand and then feed that list to the library method as a separate parameter." Really?

Comment: I already have the overall shape. Surely there is someway other than pain painstakingly handcrafting it.

Answer (score 0):

One way I could do this is to loop through all the pixels in the shape and find (and separate) those that where next to pixels that are not apart of the image.

example:

```
00111000
01111100
01111000
00111110
```

I could turn the above into

```
00111000
01000100
01001000
00111100
```

which is great but, what I really want is it to look like this:

```
00101000
01000100
01001000
00100100
```

so I could then pass 2,0 --> 4,0 --> 5,1 ...and so on